# How to get SPListItemVersion Title and Values

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

Trying to get SPListItemVerions with titles and values. My code is displaying all the versions but how do I get the item values?

```
SPListItemVersion oldVersion = listitem.Versions[i];
foreach (SPField field in oldVersion.Fields)
{
    var fiedName= field.Title;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access versions values by first getting the version collection item and then get the fields values as per usual.

```
 foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items){
    var oldVersion = item.Versions[0]["Title"];
    Console.WriteLine("{0} -- {1}", "Title", oldVersion);                                                
 }
```